# Correct way to adapt behavior based on the device size in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I am coding a basic adaptive UI using Xamarin.Forms. I have one view with a list of items in it and if you tap one of the items, it opens up a second view which show the item details. When the app is running on a phone, I want it to show a new page with the item details while when I am on a tablet, I want for the details to be shown as another view next to the original view with the list of items. What is the correct way to do this?

So far, my idea was that I would call a method in the parent page, which would decide based on the device type whether it should open up a new page or add a view to a stack layout next to the original view. I've read though that it's not exactly clean to reference the parent page from a child viewmodel, since the page method would be called by a command from the child.

Comment: You could use the `Device.Idiom` to judge the device types with `TargetIdiom Enum`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/tablet When is equals to the `Tablet` to open the view you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.targetidiom?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am just wondering whether this should be decided by the page, or by the views themselves? I want to avoid duplication of code as much as possible.

Comment: You could do the judgement when you tab one of the items. And then open the specific pages with specific device types.